# Maintenance Plan read Server Agent log

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-agent, maintenance-plan

I am new in maintenance plan and server agent. I have created two server agent job named as ABC and with type T-SQL (SELECT * FROM ABCDEFG), and server agent job named as DEF and with type T-SQL (SELECT * FROM ABC). When I execute ABC job in server agent it will appear failed, and DEF job should not execute if ABC job failed.

I create maintenance plan, with a subplan to execute ABC and DEF server agent. When I execute maintenance plan, it show Success in the job and history. Can maintenance plan job log show server agent log?

This is how my job look like :
[image]

In my server agent log it appear failed for ABC job and success for DEF job 
[image]

Maintenance plan history log
[image]

My expected result is maintenance plan will capture server agent job failed or success, if failed then stop. But base on the log, maintenance plan will execute both ABC and DEF without any dependency. How should I make both server agent job to have dependency and make sure ABC success, only execute DEF job?